# How to use my Elasticsearch query in the "q" parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I have this working query for Elasticsearch:

```
GEt /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "ranges": [
                { 
                   "from": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||-1H/H",
                   "to": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||/H" 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Due to some technical requirements of the tools that I am using, I need to convert this query to the following format, for example:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?size=0&q=*:*
```

However, instead of `q=*:*` i should place my query. Is it possible?

Comment: probably you couldn't do everything from your example to fit into just query string. Also, why do you have these requirements? Both of the example are HTTP GET requests. First have the body, and second have HTTP params. Is it that nessecary? You could take a look at Solr, where everything is coming via HTTP params and use it

Comment: @Mysterion One example would be es for spark, you can load an RDD by providing an index/type and 'q' parameters.